# Loading different templates based on dependency resolve error when using ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Assuming I have a `user` route, and I've configured the `$routeProvider` like this:

```
$routeProvider.when("/user/:id", {
   templateUrl: "templates/user.html",
   controller: "userController",
   resolve: {
      user: function(User, $route){
         // Assume that User.get(id) will return a promise for user data
         return User.get($route.current.params.id);
      }
   }
});
//...
```

## Problem:

In some circumstances,  `user` may not be resolved. For example the user may not exist (404), or current user may not have access to this user's page (403), and so on.
Like most websites, I want to use my **customized error pages** for these kinds of errors.
The problem is that template has already been fetched and I can't change it for example to ***"templates/errors/404.html"***.

### NOTE 1:

I don't want to redirect the route to something like **"/pageNotFound.html"**, because it's obviously just not right! I want the route to stay at **"/user/{id}"** while loading **"404.html"** template instead of **"user.html"**.

### NOTE 2:

One solution that I came up with is to set an **error interceptor**, and resolve promise with some **data about error**, by which I can detect the error on the controller and expose it to `scope`. So, I can use a `ng-switch` at the root of **"user.html"** that switches to different templates for normal case and different errors cases.
But I don't actually like this solution because I want to set one global 404 template for all routes that their dependencies aren't resolved because their resources are not found.

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` can be a function which takes an object of the current params (:id) as argument, but that function gets called *before* the resolve. So you could do some basic check based on the id there, but not use the results from the resolve's service call.